# understanding $P(X|Y=y)$ and $E(X|Y=y)$ for continuous random variables $X,Y$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

I am trying to read and understand a bit about conditional probability and conditional expectation. Especially, I would like to understand a bit more about what $P(X|Y=y)$ or $E(X|Y=y)$ actually mean. So I was reading the [dedicated wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_a_sub-%CF%83-algebra). It is a bit hard since I don't know that much about measure theory. In the [computation section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Computation) it is written that if both $X$ and $Y$ are continuous random variable we have ${\displaystyle \operatorname {E} (X\mid Y=y)=\int _{\mathcal {X}}xf_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)\,\mathrm {d} x,}$ where $ {\displaystyle f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)={\frac {f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_{Y}(y)}}}$.

First, what exactly is the left hand side $\operatorname {E} (X\mid Y=y)$? Is it actually $E(X|\sigma(Y=y))$ where $\sigma(Y=y)=\{(Y=y),(Y=y)^c,\Omega,\emptyset\}$ is the sigma algebra generated by the event $(Y=y)$? Then how to prove this equal to $\int_{\mathcal {X}}xf_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)\,\mathrm {d} x$?

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring measurability issues, you may simply regard the conditional probability $P(\cdot\mid Y=y)$ as a form of density:

\begin{align*}
P(A\mid Y=y)
&= \lim_{h\to0^+} P(A\mid Y\in[y,y+h]) \\
&= \lim_{h\to0^+} \frac{P(A \cap \{Y\in[y,y+h]\})}{P(Y\in[y,y+h])}
\end{align*}

Similarly,

\begin{align*}
E(X\mid Y=y)
&= \lim_{h\to0^+} E(X\mid Y\in[y,y+h]) \\
&= \lim_{h\to0^+} \frac{E(X \cdot \mathbf{1}_{\{Y\in[y,y+h]\}} )}{P(Y\in[y,y+h])}.
\end{align*}

So, if we fix $h > 0$, then by the law of total probability,

\begin{align*}
E[X \mid Y \in [y, y+h]]
& \approx \sum_{k} (kh) P(X \in [kh, (k+1)h) \mid Y \in [y, y+h]) \\
& = \sum_{k} (kh) \frac{P(\{X \in [kh, (k+1)h)\} \cap \{Y \in [y, y+h]\}}{P(Y \in [y, y+h])} \\
& \approx \sum_{k} (kh) \frac{f_{X,Y}(kh, y) h^2}{f_Y(y)h} \\
& \approx \int_{\mathbb{R}} x \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)} \, \mathrm{d}x.
\end{align*}

And we expect that the error hidden in the approximate equality $\approx$ will become smaller as $h\to0$, hence obtaining the desired identity.

Of course, all these can be derived rigorously by invoking the measure theory.

Comment: Thank you. This is very interesting. I was also interested about the measure theory aspect. I said I don't know much about measure theory more so people wouldn't assume I knew too much.